# Name for a Freudian slip in a leading question?

Tags: psychology

A leading question occurs when someone asks a question that suggests a particular answer, presumably intentionally.

Is there any special term for when this occurs *subconsciously* - i.e. when the asker reveals something about what they expect (or want) the answer to be but does so completely unknowingly?

Comment: You might find you get a more accurate answer by posting over on the [Psychology SE](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: As Vee has mentioned in his answer, we usually talk about the observer's efforts to read these signs. "Cold reading" is the ability to dial in to a speaker's unconcious verbal signalling and body language. "Giving off vibes" is the colloquial term for the sender.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this article from [FutureLearn – Logical and Critical Thinking
The University of Auckland](https://www.futurelearn.com/courses/logical-and-critical-thinking/0/steps/9163), this phenomenon is simply referred to as **unconscious cueing**.

> Wilhelm Von Osten, a German high school mathematics instructor,
>   thought that people dramatically underestimated the intelligence and
>   reasoning skills of animals.
>
> A man of science, he set out to test his hypothesis by teaching
>   mathematics to a horse called Hans. [the late C19] Hans quickly showed real aptitude;
>   soon he could read a number written on a board and tap his hoof with
>   the correct number of times.
>
> ...   ...   ...
>
> Van Osten [went on to asking the horse questions (in German). He] would ask questions such as “If the first day of the month
>   is a Wednesday, what is the date of the following Monday?” Hans would
>   tap his foot six times. “What is the square root of sixteen?” Four
>   taps.
>
> ...
>
> [This phenomenon was investigated by a young psychologist named Oskar
>   Pfungst.] Pfungst designed a careful set of experiments and began
>   testing Hans. He soon noticed that Hans performed well when questioned
>   under his normal conditions. But the horse’s accuracy dropped when the
>   questioner stood farther away than normal. And if the questioner
>   didn’t know the answer to a question or was concealed from him, Hans’
>   accuracy plummeted to nearly zero. Pfungst hypothesized that Hans’
>   cleverness relied on him having a close, unobstructed view of a person
>   who knew the correct answer.
>
> With that in mind, Pfungst began watching the questioners, and he
>   noticed that as Hans tapped his hoof in response to a question, their
>   breathing, posture, and expression showed subtle signs of increasing
>   tension, tension which disappeared when Hans made the correct tap.
>   Innocently and without realizing they were doing so, Pfungst
>   concluded, the questioners were giving Hans a cue when to stop
>   tapping.
>
> Pfungst had discovered ‘**unconscious cueing**’, the influence of
>   researchers’ subtle and unintentional signals on their subjects, and
>   it is now recognized as widespread in research involving human
>   subjects as well as animals.

I remember being warned about the need to avoid cueing answers when in teacher training.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it would be referred to in psychology as observer-expectancy effect. It is essentially a form of researcher’s bias, where the researcher subconsciously projects what they would like to see or hear from the participant.

Hope this was the answer you were looking for.